# spring boot java one call but has two times @Transactional can get error when executed insert data in the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

Can someone please clarify whether the transaction can stall when writing data to the database when I have the following case:

```
  @Transactional
  public void methodOne(List<Long> ids) {
        this.methodTwo(ids);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void methodTwo(List<Long> ids) {
        testRepository.deleteData(ids);
        testRepository.insertData(ids);;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your transaction will be valid. By default `@Transactional` have **REQUIRED Propagation**

> REQUIRED is the default propagation. Spring checks if there is an active transaction, and if nothing exists, it creates a new one. Otherwise, the business logic appends to the currently active transaction

So when you call `methodOne` it has already `@Transactional`. So it will start the transaction and `methodTwo` will continue using that transaction.

More info at [Transaction Propagation and Isolation in Spring @Transactional](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation)